# Is there a VBA command that causes a debug to start at that point?

Tags: vba, excel

The context of this question is that I am using message boxes as a tool to help me get familiar with a quite large amount of VBA macros that are running on a collection of Excel workbooks.

I am carefully inserting message boxes within the code which pop up and tell/remind me where we are in the code.
I would like to have a button in these boxes which will take me into a debug of the code at that point.

At the moment my solution is to perform a division-by-zero if the `Yes' button is chosen.
Here is an example snippet:

```
Dim MyError as Double
...
If MsgBox("Just entered function XYZ(). Want to debug?", vbYesNo + vbDefaultButton2) = vbYes Then MyError = 1# / 0
```

It works, but is not very elegant.

I was hoping there is a command which will start the VBA debug mode at the point that command is called.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The `Stop` command does this for you:

```
If MsgBox("Just entered function XYZ(). Want to debug?", vbYesNo + vbDefaultButton2) = vbYes Then Stop
```

Answer (score 9):

Yes, there is:

```
Debug.Assert False
```

Comment: so you could also use:

    Debug.Assert (MsgBox("Just entered function XYZ(). Want to debug?", vbYesNo + vbDefaultButton2) = vbYes)